# Multiple bibtex styles for each type of reference

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, citing, bibliographystyle, footcite

As indicated in the title, I am trying to use several styles of  `bibtex` on the same document.
Specifically, I would like to differentiate how I display citations in for `online` references, from how I display citations for `book` and `article` ones.
My need is to use `footcite` so that I can write in full the site from which I have taken the reference, whereas I would like to have citations of `book` and `article` displayed with a number and to be able to put them in square brackets.
Consider that at the moment, if I use `\cite` in book and article, I find the entire reference within the text.
The following is an MWE of what is currently happening.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=verbose-ibid,hyperref,backref]{biblatex}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}

\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}
  
\begin{document}

Cite book: \cite{ian:swe}\\

Cite article: \cite{paper:jira}\\

Cite website: \footcite{site:agile-manifesto}

\cleardoublepage
\chapter{Bibliografia}

% Print book bibliography
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography,title={Riferimenti bibliografici},type=book]

% Print articles/paper
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography,title={Pubblicazioni scientifiche},type=article]

% Print site bibliography
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography,title={Siti web consultati},type=online]

\end{document}
```

`bibliography.bib`

```
@book{ian:swe,
    title={Ingegneria del software},
    author={Ian Sommerville},
    isbn={9788891902245},
    url={https://www.pearson.it/opera/pearson/0-6424-ingegneria_del_software},
    year={2017},
    publisher={Pearson}
}

@online{site:agile-manifesto,
    title   = {Manifesto Agile},
    url     = {https://agilemanifesto.org/iso/it/manifesto.html}
}

@article{paper:jira,
    author  = {Diamantopoulos, Themistoklis and Saoulidis, Nikolaos and Symeonidis, Andreas},
    year    = {2023},
    month   = {05},
    title   = {Automated issue assignment using topic modelling on Jira issue tracking data},
    volume  = {17},
    journal = {IET Software},
    doi = {10.1049/sfw2.12129}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current style `verbose-ibid` will display citations in full. To use the bracket you need the style `numeric`. Then to display full citations in footnotes for online sources, you need to use `\footfullcite`.

However, note this will assign numbers to the online sources, which will not come back in the text.

So your citations will look like this:
[image: example of the citations]

And the bibliography like this:
[image: example of the bibliography]

Comment: This is actually ok. But my actual idea was to "avoid" the numbering of the online sources. Any ideas?

Comment: It is tough because you use `hyperref` and `backref`. Otherwise the `multibib` would provide an option.